# Django: URL pattern produces incorrect referer

Tags: python, django

I've got a url pattern

```
url(r'^(?P<offer_id>[^/]+)/$', detail, name="detail"),
```

which passes the `offer_id` to the view called `detail`. My problem is the page this view produces has the HTTP referer as itself instead of the original. i.e. the http referer for mysite.com/offer1/ ends up being itself.

Can I change this so the referer is actually the original page the user clicked the link from?
If I can't would this have an effect for Google spidering my site? I assume some sort of  redirection is going on, would search engines look down on this?

**update**

Using Chromes developer tools, it seems that for pages already in the (browser?) cache the request headers are missing. For pages not in the cache the request headers are there and the referer data is correct, but `request.META.HTTP_REFERER` in the `detail` template still refers to the current page not the referer

Comment: Are you sure you're calling it with the trailing slash? Django may be automatically redirecting for you if you're calling with the URL `http://mysite.com/offer1`.

Comment: Great idea! But all the links do have a trailing slash `http://mysite.com/offer1/`

Comment: In that case I recommend installing the Django Debug Toolbar https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar and turning on `INTERCEPT_REDIRECTS` to better understand what Django's doing under the hood (and confirm that in fact a redirect is occurring).

Comment: That debug toolbar is great, thank you for putting me on to it. I've enabled INTERCEPT_REDIRECTS and according to the docs "the debug toolbar will show an intermediate page upon redirect" i'm not getting shown any intermediate page so I assume no redirect is infact happening